# Google Text to Speech API

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

I want to convert text to speech in my server side application (no chrome, no android sdk), does google have a text to speech api.
Tried looking at  http://translate.google.com/translate_tts however that is blocked for api access.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) What exactly is your programming question??

Comment: I would like to know if there is way to convert text to speech using any google api to be used in custom application.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, **no**. But there are a bunch of libraries that will let you do that, for example [say.js](https://github.com/marak/say.js/).